# Odoo - Print multiple jasper reports from tree view

Tags: python, jasper-reports, odoo-9

In Odoo (v9), when I print a **report of an individual** customer invoice, **jasper report** works fine. But when I try to print reports of **multiple** number of customer invoices from the **tree view**, I get **singleton error**. Is there something else to be done in **ireport** for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Report group*** is used for solving this. In the **.py file** of **jasper report**:

- **Pass** the field by which we want to "group", via the dictionary vals{ }, along with other fields. I used **group by "invoice_id"**.

  ```
  vals = {'invoice_id' : invoice.id}
  ```
- **Sort** the result by "invoice_id" after appending the dictionary.

  ```
  result.append(vals)
  result = sorted(result, key=lambda d: (d['invoice_id']))   
  return result
  ```

In **ireport**:

- Right click on the file name inside ireport
- Add Report Group
- Give a Group name
- Group by following report object: "invoice_id"
- Add a group header and group footer
- Set the properties of group header as: **start on a new page**
- Compile